# Data not getting added to firebase when trying to save it in the initState() method

Tags: flutter, firebase, riverpod

Here's `initState()` method code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      ref.read(chatHistoryControllerProvider).initializeChat();
    });
  }
```

Here's the `initializeChat()` method:

```
Future<void> initializeChat() async {
    print(currentUser?.uid);
    final data = {"roomName": "New Chat", "initializedAt": Timestamp.now()};
    await db
        .collection('aaa')
        .doc(currentUser?.uid)
        .collection('bbb')
        .add(data)
        .then((value) {
      print(value.id);
      ref.read(chatIdProvider.notifier).state = value.id;
      db
          .collection('aaa')
          .doc(currentUser?.uid)
          .collection('bbb')
          .doc(ref.watch(chatIdProvider))
          .collection('ccc')
          .doc('ccc')
          .set(ccc);
    });
  }
```

Here's a screenshot of the database:

[image]

The `currentUser.uid` and `value.id` is getting printed but the `final data = {"roomName": "New Chat", "initializedAt": Timestamp.now()};` is not getting saved in the firebase, instead it is showing "*This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots*" while the collection `ccc` is being shown.

Please help.

Comment: Can you check if your method is called at all?

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat it is getting called as `currentUser.uid` and `value.id` is getting printed

Comment: Do you have the collections created in Firabase?

Comment: If `print(value.id);` runs, the data **has** been written to the `bbb` collection on the server. There is no way for the `then` block to be called any other way.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know it doesn't make any sense. I have added a screenshot of the database in the question. Please check.